# how to authorize users in all pages and respond according to the type of request(ajax or not) in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

how to authurize users in all pages and

if request is a "ajax request" then response by Json format

and if request not a "ajax request" noramly response

for Example:

If the request was not Ajax, go to the login page and if the request was ajax, then it would open login modal on the same page screen

note: I'm looking for a way to apply the whole project, not every single actions

Comment: So you want `Custom Authorization`?

Comment: yes i want Custom Authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I written same sample code of Authorization attribute. if IsAjaxRequest() then response with JsonResult.

Additionally, check session exists of not. To apply across all controller you need to add attribute on class level. `[ClassName]`

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
 if (filterContext != null)
  {
    BaseController baseController = (BaseController)filterContext.Controller;
    string controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;

    if (!baseController.SessionStore.ItemExists(SessionKeys.CEHCKSESSIONEXIST))
    {
        if (baseController.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {
                Data = new { Status = CommonConstants.SessionTimeout },
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
            };
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
            { "Controller", "Integration" },
            { "Action", "SessionExpired" }
         });
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can create custom AuthorizeAttribute and override HandleUnauthorizedRequest method Like this

```
 public class AjaxAuthorizeAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                UrlHelper urlhelper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                {
                    Data = new
                    {
                        Error = "NotAuthorize",
                        LogOnUrl = urlhelper.Action("LogOn", "Account")
                    },
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                };
            }else
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use Attribute filter. Create a custom attribute like

in your controller you can override OnActionExecuting

```
  protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    bool isAjaxCall = Context.Request.Headers["x-requested-with"]=="XMLHttpRequest" /// in aspnet core.
   isAjax= Request.IsAjax() ///in aspnet 5
    If(isAjaxCall) // handle if request is ajax.
   {
    //return json 
        context.Result = Ok("something in json");
   }
  else{

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

      }

}
```